# Using if statement in string_agg function - postreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

The query is as follows

```
WITH notes AS (
    SELECT 891090 Order_ID, False customer_billing,  false commander, true agent 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 891091, false, true, true 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 891091, true, false, false)

SELECT
  n.order_id,
  string_Agg(distinct CASE
    WHEN n.customer_billing = TRUE THEN 'AR (Customer Billing)'
    WHEN n.commander = TRUE THEN 'AP (Commander)'
    WHEN n.agent = TRUE THEN 'AP (Agent)'
    ELSE NULL
  END,', ') AS finance
FROM notes n
WHERE
 n.order_id = 891091 AND (n.customer_billing = TRUE or n.commander = TRUE or n.agent = TRUE)
 GROUP BY ORDER_ID
```

As you can see there are two records with order_id as **891091**.

- First 891091 record has `commander` and `agent` set as true
- Second 891091 record has `customer_billing` set as true

Since switch case is used, it considers only the first true value and returns `commander` and does not consider `agent`.

So the output becomes

```
order_id    finance
891091  AP (Commander), AR (Customer Billing)
```

[dbfiddle.uk Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=117f63d22b81bef8ab52d148f91d4f4c)

I need all the true values in the record to be considered so that the output becomes

```
order_id    finance
    891091  AP (Commander), AP (Agent), AR (Customer Billing)
```

My initial thought is that using if statement instead of case statement may fix this. I am not sure how to do this inside string_agg function

How to achieve this?

EDIT 1:

The answer specified below works almost fine. But the issue is that the comma separated values are not **distinct**

Here is the updated fiddle
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9647d92870e3944516172eda83a8ac6e

Comment: `mysql` or `postgresql`, thats the question .... (Please delete the tag that is not correct!)

Comment: What dbms did you use? your dbfiddle use Postgres but your title wrote mysql

Comment: postrgesql is used. I have removed the unnecessary tag

Comment: For 1 record `customer_billing` is true => 'AR (Customer Billing)' is added, for another record `commander` is true => 'AP (Commander)' is added.    Maybe rea about [PostgreSQL SELECT DISTINCT](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/#:~:text=The%20DISTINCT%20clause%20is%20used,list%20of%20the%20SELECT%20statement.)

Comment: SELECT 891091, false, true, true . Here commander and agent are true.

Comment: see this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1fb14a62a0e2b24c296c4f0bd409bebd

Comment: @Luuk this doesnt work. Since CASE is used, and a single record has both agent and commander set as true, it returns the first matching element and ignores the second.

Comment: @prajeesh: It was not clear (to me) that  both `agent` and `command` should be returned, see my addition on my https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ca44d4e66b9331d58d535b4cb385f6e0

Comment: @Luuk 891091 AP (Commander), AR (Customer Billing). This is the output of the db fiddle that you posted. Still it does not have agent. The output should be like https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5fa36a02eaaebb462b27179e40a7501a

Comment: No, the output from my fiddle is: "AR (Customer Billing), AP (Commander), AP (Agent)", the output from yours is "AP (Commander), AR (Customer Billing), AP (Agent)", the output in your question is "AP (Commander), AP (Agent), AR (Customer Billing)".  So now we have 3 different possibilities ... 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider splitting your `case` into separate ones and using array to collect them. Then you can use `array_to_string` to format:

```
WITH notes AS (
  SELECT 891090 Order_ID, False customer_billing,  false commander, true agent UNION ALL
  SELECT 891091, false, true, true UNION ALL
  SELECT 891091, true, true, false),
tmp as (
SELECT
  n.order_id id,
      array_agg(
        ARRAY[
          CASE WHEN n.customer_billing = TRUE THEN 'AR (Customer Billing)' END,
          CASE WHEN n.commander = TRUE THEN 'AP (Commander)' END,
          CASE WHEN n.agent = TRUE THEN 'AP (Agent)' END
        ]) AS finance_array
FROM notes n
WHERE
 n.order_id = 891091 AND (n.customer_billing = TRUE or n.commander = TRUE or n.agent = TRUE)
 GROUP BY ORDER_ID )
 select id, array_to_string(array(select distinct e from unnest(finance_array) as a(e)), ', ')
 from tmp;
```

Here is [db_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5fa36a02eaaebb462b27179e40a7501a).

Comment: This works almost correct. The issue here is that the comma separated values are not distinct. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b4082b4d190439e2655a9624b0a599a6

Comment: @prajeesh you're totally correct, I forgot about that case. I have corrected the answer, please have a look at the snippet